# Perl script not working through EPIC plug in in Eclipse

Tags: perl, selenium, webdriver, epic

I have the below Perl script in my eclipse:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
print "Hello, World!\n";
my $name = "king";
print "Hello, $name!\n";
my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver('browser_name' => 'firefox');   
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');
print $driver->get_title();
$driver->quit();
```

**Output :**

```
Hello, World!                                        
Hello, king!                                              
Selenium server did not return proper status at (eval 91) line 64.
```

Why I am getting the error message:

```
"Selenium server did not return proper status at (eval 91) line 64"
```

The browser is not starting. Kindly help if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: Have you run selenium webdriver using `java -jar pathtowebdriver/selenium-server-standalone-2.43.0.jar`?

Comment: Hi Chankey, Just now i did that , after running  the firefox is opened but i got the below error Hello, World!
Hello, king!
Could not create new session: HASH(0x3f0e3e8) at (eval 76) line 482.

Comment: Which version of firefox and webdriver are you using? I tested this on `selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0` and `firefox 33.0`. It worked fine. Try using latest version of both.

Comment: Hi Chankey, I am using firefox 34.0 and  and selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0 . I cannot change it due do my projecr restriction . Can u tell me how we can do this in CHROME. How to set the system properties .

Comment: According to the bug mentioned here: https://github.com/gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/issues/127#issuecomment-44372561 you must be using Selenium 2.42 or greater.

Comment: hurray... !!! It  is working after adding selenium-44. Thank you very much friend Chankey  :)

Comment: You are welcome, please mark the answer as accepted in that case :) See [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: by the way, although you should be using the latest anyways, the issue mentioned here https://github.com/gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/issues/127#issuecomment-44372561 is not a bug. The reporter simply upgraded and the issue went away. Which can also be due to a misconfiguration of some type. just an FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Add `use strict; use warnings;` at the top after `shebang` and make sure the selenium standalone server is running.

So steps would be

1. Run selenium server: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar`

Observe below output

```
➤ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
15:18:56.677 INFO - Launching a standalone server
15:18:56.900 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.40-b25
15:18:56.900 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
15:18:56.914 INFO - v2.44.0, with Core v2.44.0. Built from revision 76d78cf
15:18:57.174 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
15:18:57.175 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
15:18:57.176 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
15:18:57.325 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@af7cc2
15:18:57.325 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
15:18:57.325 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
15:18:57.325 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
15:18:57.329 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
15:18:57.329 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@133314b
```

2. Run your script.

I tested this on selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0 and firefox 33.0. It worked fine.

**Update:** According to the bug mentioned [here](https://github.com/gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/issues/127#issuecomment-44372561) you must be using Selenium 2.42 or greater.

Comment: I have done that . Browser is started but getting the error  -Could not create new session: HASH(0x3f01a18) at (eval 76) line 482.

Comment: Which version of webdriver are you using? Try 2.44.